# Echo "part" of array (decoded from JSON)

Tags: arrays, echo

I'am quite new to JSON and more "advanced" arrays. Therefore I don't know what I should search for...

I have this "JSON array" (what do you call it?):

```
{
   "id": "321123321",
   "statuses": {
      "data": [
         {
            "message": "testmessage",
            "updated_time": "2012-12-25T16:33:29+0000",
            "id": "123321123"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "previous": "1",
         "next": "1"
      }
   }
}​
```

I want to create a variable from "message" that is called $message and a variable from "up_datedtime" that is called $updated.

To get id I simple:
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
$id $json_a['id'];

And for statuses: 
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
$status = $json_a['id']['statuses'];

But when I try to get "message" I get " Cannot use string offset as an array in":
    $message = $json_a['id']['statuses']['data']['message'];

How do I get $message from the array the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this

```
$message = $json_a['id']['statuses']['data'][0]['message'];
```

or you can get from loop

```
$dataArr = $json_a['id']['statuses']['data'];

foreach ($dataArr as $val) {
    echo "message".$val['message'];
}
```

Comment: $message = $json_a['id']['statuses']['data'][0]['message'];
    echo $message;"

Gives me "Cannot use string offset as an array i". I have googled the error, but I have not found any solution for my problem...

Comment: then u can debug by printing step by step like, print_r( $json_a['id']['statuses']['data']);

Comment: print_r( $json_a['id']['statuses']); works fine, but print_r( $json_a['id']['statuses']['data']); gives me this error: " Cannot use string offset as an array in". What should I do to avoid the error?